# Why am I getting this error with my for loop?

Tags: java

```
public boolean isNumber(String t) {
    for (int i = 0, i<= 9, i++) {
        if t.equals(i) {
                return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Copypastad the wrong method originally -*_*-
 I have this inside a class compiling with this error:

data_structures/ExpressionEvaluator.java:40: illegal start of type for (int i = 0, i< 10, i++) {

Comment: you should probably show your actual loop. I don't see anything wrong with this.

Comment: error is no way pointing the code you have pasted here. More code may help.

Comment: Why did you post that code when it's unrelated?

Comment: Your method will never return true.

Answer (score 3):

Use semi-colons instead of commas.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    //do stuff
}
```

Comment: Lol wow I had the wrong language in my head when I wrote this. Flagged for removal for "dumb." Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You should use semi-colon and your `if` should be surrounded with brackets.

```
public boolean isNumber(String t) {
    for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++) {
        if (t.equals(i)) {
                return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

I would suggest reading  [Language Basics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/)

Answer (score 0):

Semicolons separate the qualities of a for loop.  Also, the condition of your if block must be surrounded by parentheses.

```
public boolean isNumber(String t) {
    for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++) {
        if (t.equals(i)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean isNumber(String t) {
    for (int i = 0; i<= 9; i++) {
        if( t.equals(i) ){
                return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

1 . use ";" replace of ","

2 .

```
if(boolean) {
        //do stuff
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your method only verifies if the String that you passed is a digit, not a number (a number can have more than one digit). You could verifiy it only using a char and calling the ,`Character.isDigit`

```
char c = '1';
boolean isDigit = Character.isDigit(c);
```

If you really want to create your own method, passing a String param, I suggest you to modify like this:

```
public boolean isDigit(String t) {
    return t.length() == 1 && Character.isDigit(t.charAt(0));
}
```